# TListView MouseUp event fires too early and MouseMove Shift doesn't work as expected either

Tags: c++, c, delphi, c++builder, vcl

Using C++ Builder 2009 (but I tagged Delphi too since this is VCL)

I created a class that inherits from `TListView` and when there are no objects to list, I '`DrawText`' some text in the middle of the `ListView` `Canvas`, but with a hotspot in the text that can be clicked.
Basically I draw the text using two colors and the hotspot area is in blue.
I also keep track of the coordinates of that hotspot in a custom HotSpot class.

PS. I use `MultiSelect = true`

When I hover with the mouse over the hotspot I want to underline the text (which works using below code)

When I release a mouse click on the hotspot I want it to call an event (which works in below code, if `MultiSelect = true`)

But I also wanted to display the text in bold when the hotspot is clicked (MouseDown) before released again (MouseUp).
This doesn't work because the MouseDown code is not executed when the mouse is clicked, it only executes when the mouse click gets released and only just before the MouseUp code.  Is this a bug ?

However the logic changes when `MultiSelect` is off (= `false`), the MouseUp event then triggers straight after MouseDown, but *before* the mouse button is released

So I figured I ignore MouseDown and put the logic in MouseMove and check Shift for the left mouse click.  Yet that never works when `MultiSelect = true`, only when `MultiSelect = false`, which doesn't work for my needs because MouseUp triggers too fast.

Is there something obvious I'm missing ?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall ObjectListView::MouseMove(Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
TListView::MouseMove(Shift, X, Y);

if (Items->Count == 0 && HotSpot.Rect.Top > 0)
    {
    if (InRange(X, HotSpot.Rect.Left, HotSpot.Rect.Right) && InRange(Y, HotSpot.Rect.Top, HotSpot.Rect.Bottom))
        {
        if (!HotSpot.Hover)
            {
            HotSpot.Hover = true ;
            Invalidate() ; // Paint the text again, but this time Hot
            }

        if (Shift.Contains(ssLeft)) // Left Mouse button is being held down
            {
            if (!HotSpot.Select)
                {
                HotSpot.Select = true ;
                Invalidate() ; // Paint the text again, but this time Selected
                }
            }
        else if (HotSpot.Select)
            {
            HotSpot.Select = false ;
            Invalidate() ;
            }
        }
    else if (HotSpot.Hover)
        {
        HotSpot.Hover = false ;
        HotSpot.Select = false;
        Invalidate() ;
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall ObjectListView::MouseUp(TMouseButton Button, Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
TListView::MouseUp(Button, Shift, X, Y);

if (OnHotSpotClick && Items->Count == 0 && HotSpot.Rect.Top > 0)
    {
    if (Button == mbLeft)
        {
        if (InRange(X, HotSpot.Rect.Left, HotSpot.Rect.Right) && InRange(Y, HotSpot.Rect.Top, HotSpot.Rect.Bottom))
            {
            HotSpot.Select = false ;
            Invalidate() ;
            OnHotSpotClick(this, ParentObject, (TLVStatus)HotSpot.Data) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall ObjectListView::MouseDown(TMouseButton Button, Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
TListView::MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);

// This event triggers when the mouse button is released (Bug ?) and if (MultiSelect == true)
// So there is no point trying to do something with the HotSpot state
// Instead, use the MouseMove event and check the Shift state
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried capturing the Windows message ( WM_LBUTTONDOWN ) and noticed that it fires at the same time, so it's not VCL delaying the event as far as I can tell.  I assume this is Windows behaviour then ?